# Laravel bootstrap via Vite npm run dev ReferenceError: path is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap, vite

Помогите разобраться как же все таки подключить bootstrap в Laravel 10.20 ...

Вчера я выполнил такие действия для его подключения

**1) установил пакет и запустил сборку (если я правильно понял как это называется)**

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install
npm run dev
```

**2) в vite.config.js сделал так**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/sass/app.scss',
                'resources/js/bootstrap.js',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
        }
    },
});
```

**3) в resources/js/app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';

import '../sass/app.scss'

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

**4) resources/js/bootstrap.js**

```
import * as Popper from '@popperjs/core'
window.Popper = Popper

import 'bootstrap';

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

**5) во view**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    {{-- ... --}}
 
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
```

И все работало! Но сегодня (после того как я перезагрузил ПК), бутсрапп не работает, а в консоли при попытки выполнить

```
npm run dev
```

Я получаю вот такую ошибку

```
> dev
> vite

failed to load config from /var/www/crm.itscript.local/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at file:///var/www/crm.itscript.local/vite.config.js.timestamp-1705857609380-fbb3f1ecb72ff.mjs:18:21
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
    введите сюда код
```

Как понять в чем тут причина, что требуется сделать, в каком направлении "копать" ?

P/S только начал изучение Laravel

Comment: В `vite.config.js` добавьте `const path = require('path');`

Comment: добавил, не помогло https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OMjYioUL5A0hy2vjMKxHOJQupYvnL0Mj/view?usp=sharing как вообще это дебажить?

Comment: Другая ошибка. Попробуйте так: `import { resolve } from 'path';` и `'~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),` => `'~bootstrap': resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),`

Comment: @InDevX спасибо большое, так заработало! 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/11jKCyIPjIjJa0K4f4-4egJNo9GGKT2yw/view?usp=sharing Хотелось бы понять почему это работает только после запуска npm run dev ? Я подозреваю что происходит некая компиляция ресурсов... но что я должен буду на продакшне также эту команду запустить, и как ее запустить что бы после выхода из консоли у меня bootstrap не отвалился? И еще бы хотелось понять что я сделал используя ваш пример кода? Какие то пути поменял? Но как их определять правильно что бы самостоятельно это выполнить в следующий раз?

Comment: `npm run dev` собирает пакеты и они используются после сборки с разными фичами аля смена модуля на лету, для прода надо запускать `npm run build` собирает и оптимизирует файлы. Для прода надо Ошибка была в том что path не определялась, мы её просто добавили (верней, тут уже не сам объект а напрямую ф-ю resolve()), пути никакие не менял. Как определять - ошибку читать) 90% ответа содержится в ошибке.

Comment: так а как мне на dev один раз запустить и пользоваться? Или мне надо каждый раз запускать npm run dev пока я веду разработку, для того что бы например мои изменения в /resources/css/app.css ?

Comment: для разработки npm run dev то есть если что-то меняться будет в файлах кот. билдятся, если ничего меняться не будет то можно сбилдить (npm run build) и не надо будет каждый раз npm run dev запускать

Comment: а после npm run build ничего в конфиге vite.config.js менять не нужно будет?

Comment: не нужно, билд используя этот конфиг создает скомпилированные js,css файлы и они подключаются автоматом когда тег прописан в blade

Comment: какой тег и где прописан в каком файле?